# Facebook OpenGraph metadata - Punycoded domains (with scandic / special characters) not decoded

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-opengraph, punycode

Facebook doesn't seem to understand to decode punycoded domains with OpenGraph og:url metatag

Take a look into this example - type "kämp pikset .fi" (please remove the spaces, I don't want this question to get indexed for that keyword):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I think this a shortcoming with Facebook's OpenGraph parsing... Is there a way around this?

Update: I have filed a problem report with Facebook.

Comment: What is not working? I tested and it seems to work for me

Comment: WixKid - Facebook should display the domain with the special characters decoded (og:url as shown below the title "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties"), but instead the punycoded domain is shown.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs